# Problem with install cryptography 1.1 for python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, python-2.7

Did someone reach the same problem while installing cryptography 1.1 for Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04?

```
reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
building '_openssl' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:695:6: error: conflicting types for ‘BIO_new_mem_buf’
 BIO *BIO_new_mem_buf(void *, int);
      ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:65:0,
                 from build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:411:
/usr/include/openssl/bio.h:692:6: note: previous declaration of ‘BIO_new_mem_buf’ was here
 BIO *BIO_new_mem_buf(const void *buf, int len);
      ^
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I install all requirements from [cryptography docs](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux)

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
```

But I have still the same problem. 
For the newest cryptography version (1.4) and as for the Ubuntu 14.04 the problem is does not appear . But I need to use version 1.1 and Ubuntu 16.04.

So have somebody an idea what is the reason? Any proposal?

@gertvdijk
I check your proposal to use cryptography==1.1.2 instead 1.1, but it gives the same results.

My question is: Are someone reach the same problem as me? Is any chance that I can use old version of cryptography==1.1 in Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7?

Comment: Any specific reason for using the older 1.1 version of cryptography? Many issues with OpenSSL have been solved in newer versions. Also, if you cannot upgrade to a newer version at least try also 1.1.2 which incorporates some fixes while keeping backward compatibility. As your question currently stands it's not really answerable. The only way forward is to keep your libraries up to date if you want to run on newer Ubuntu versions.

Comment: @gertvdijk Thank you for answer. 
_Any specific reason for using the older 1.1 version of cryptography?_

The reason is simple: this is a requirement of the web service code which I got to check. I asked the project manager if they can change to a newer version - so now I way for decision. And meanwhile I am looking for another solution.

_Many issues with OpenSSL have been solved in newer versions._
So as I understand it correctly the problem depends on OpenSSL libraries.

_if you cannot upgrade to a newer version at least try also 1.1.2_
I will try this solution tomorrow.